# Can not read all posts on my facebook wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm reading fine my application wall posts with this call:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$appid.'/posts?'.$access_token);`

But I'm only getting the posts that I have published myself.
For other users theirs posts seem to appear in another list (filter=3)

`http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=<app-id>&v=wall&filter=3`

Is there a way to disable this filtering ?
Is there a way to read these posts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the *wrong* method/connection :-)
Have a look at the [`application`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/) document (or the `user` also):

> posts     The applications's **own** posts

What you need to call is the `feed` connection.

Comment: Although I had read it, i missed the difference between feed & post.