# retrieve facebook page posts from everyone

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, posts, facebook-page

i want to retrieve all posts on a facebook page, but using the graph api, all i can retrieve are those which posted by the owner of the page.

i use the following

```
http://graph.facebook.com/nilecatacombs/posts
```

which gives me the posts written by owner.

on the page http://www.facebook.com/nilecatacombs, if you click Nile + others, the returning results are what i need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can not read all posts on my facebook wall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923246/can-not-read-all-posts-on-my-facebook-wall)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this fql:

PHP code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT post_id, actor_id, message, created_time, attachment, comments, likes, permalink FROM stream WHERE source_id = ' . $page_id . ' limit 50';
```

it worked for me.

Comment: Matej, you are awesome. It is absolutely working, and you got me out from a very desperate situation.Thank you so much.